# How to see what cells are being referenced in sumif statement from another sheet in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How to see what cells are being referenced from a sumif statement in google sheets?
i am using this forumla

```
=sumifs('Sheet 2'!$E:$E,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A,">="&T$4,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A,"<="&T$5,'Sheet 2'!$DG:$DG,$A$4)
```

and that gives me 40 000 and I know that it is only supposed to return 35 000.
Now I want to understand which cells this function is summing....but these cells are in another sheet... how to see what cells are being referenced?

Comment: Im not sure I understand, you want to just visually see what cells are being used? Can you provide an example sheet? Though maybe Player0's answer solves your issue?

Comment: @iansedano exactly! i want to visually see what cells are being used. 
But the cells are on page 2. And so when i click the cell where the formula is in, and then go to page 2, the cells which i would want to see are not being selected. How do I keep them selected while I switch through the tabs?/sheets?/pages?

Answer (score 0):

change sumif for filter:

```
=FILTER('Sheet 2'!E:E, 
 'Sheet 2'!A:A, ">="&T4,
 'Sheet 2'!A:A, "<="&T5,
 'Sheet 2'!DG:DG, A4)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm afraid that is not possible

I think this could potentially be a useful feature, to be able to visually have a pop-up or something that will illustrate the range that is being used.

That said, it is more complicated than what you might think. If you start working with large ranges for example, it might make things go very slowly.

It may be quite difficult to implement, and a question that would be asked is:

> Why can you not just take a note of the range and see for yourself?

Which is what I might do in this case.

There is the possibility, while you are *writing* your function, to go to another sheet.

[image]

As you can see, you can go to another sheet to select a range and when you press ENTER, the sheet goes back to the original sheet.

The other thing you can do is to request this feature by going to the HELP menu > "Help Sheets Improve" and write your request there.